# Use callback response as another function argument

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am using a geocoder API which returns result in a callback

```
data = data ? data : {} // if not given initialize to empty
geocoder.geocode('Kathmandu, Nepal' , function(err, res) {
data.lat = res[0].latitude;
data.lng = res[0].longitude;
});
```

and using the data `object` to construct a Geopoint

```
here = new GeoPoint(here); // data is still {} here
```

My question is how to use response from callback in above scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geocode` method is async - so any work you want to do with the response needs to be in the callback:

```
geocoder.geocode('Kathmandu, Nepal' , function(err, res) {
    data.lat = res[0].latitude;
    data.lng = res[0].longitude;

    here = new GeoPoint(here); //HAS TO BE IN A CALLBACK 
    //- or passed to another function from within the callback
});
```